Do we need tags for Copilot?
Reading the recent question How to accept autocompletion suggestions in Vim from Github Copilot with TAB key?, I had the feeling it needed a tag related to GitHub Copilot. As these things are now entering the mainstream, I would assume the number of questions about AI assistants to increase over time.
A quick full text search for Copilot showed there already exist several related (and some unrelated) questions.
My initial idea was to stick to the system of having one tag per plugin and create plugin-copilot.
I'm having doubts as this seems a bit unspecific. Every company calls their AI gadget "copilot" these days. So the tag might get abused. On the other hand, that's what the plugin's called.
I wondered if we needed a more specific github-copilot for interactions with that service, regardless of how it's done. Or maybe a tag for all kinds of AI-related questions but that might be too broad.
Is the existing external-command the way to go in these cases? From Vim's point of view, it hardly matters whether some text comes from an AI tool or, say, cat foo.txt.
What do you think about it?

The example question is clearly about GitHub Copilot from the original title.
If tags are needed, I think plugin-github-copilot is the clearest. A github-copilot would have to be limited to questions about using the tool with Vim and not the plugin, I guess? I’m not sure how that could be useful, but I don’t see harm in having both at the moment.
Certainly copilot or plugin-copilot is ambiguous.
I would also prefer something like external-command over a tag for every tool, though that tag wiki might need updated to cover it “officially.” Generally I think good questions can be external data source-agnostic except when the details of the source matter.
If tags are intended to help answerers find good questions, I see an argument to be made that using the specific tool is more helpful. I don’t think it’s worth over-specifying without volume, however.

PS Arguably, the name of the plugin is github/copilot.vim; the “basename” of plugins hosted on software forges that follow this pattern can be ambiguous, and many Vimmers refer to such plugins with this full(er) name. (It is only slightly less ambiguous because it makes an implicit assumption that folks will use that as the name of a GitHub repository. There are other source forges, but that’s a rant for another day.)

Thank you for your answer. The name [plugin-github-copilot] crossed my mind but I disliked it for its length and inconsistency with other plugin tags. I can agree with your argument. I thought to use [github-copilot] for exactly what you wrote but now I think [external-command] could be used in those cases.

And: yes, it's obvious the question is about Github Copilot. I edited my question and removed my flawed rationale.

I think we can now close this question. Since we were beaten to it and a [plugin-copilot] was created, how would you like to proceed? I can retag the 10 questions to use [plugin-github-copilot] or should we just drop the matter altogether?

@Friedrich I think I would prefer the former but I don’t feel strongly.
